# Can someone help me set up dual boot Win7 and Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, veracrypt

I have Win 7 and latest ubuntu on 500 gb drive. Dual boot worked fine, till I decided to install VeraCrypt and now I lost my ability to boot into Ubuntu. When I press ESC in veracrypt boot loader 1.21, it bypasses boot to Win 7 and stops with a message:

```
Bootable Partitions: Drive:0, Partition:2, Size:149633MB ... Booting
```

I'm trying to set up Ubuntu to boot from this point. I'm new to linux/Ubuntu. The 2 unknown partitions (in the image) are NTFS partitions.

Screen shot of my disk from GParted:

[image: GParted screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Veracrypt/Truecrypt replaces the boot loader when you tell it to set up full disk encryption in Windows. This erases Ubuntu's boot loader Grub. It would be easy to restore the boot loader with a live system but that will in turn erase Veracrypt's/Truecrypt's boot loader and may render the encrypted Windows file systems unbootable and ***potentially inaccessible*** (unlikely but possible; see the recommendation below for more).

I recommend that you

- either install Veracrypt for Linux in your live system and try to decrypt and mount the encrypted volumes without Veracrypt's boot loader to verify that you won't loose your data when you restore Grub
- or, if you have a second internal drive, install Grub into the boot sector of that drive which, as a side effect, should allow you to "chain-boot" any other boot loaders on other drives or partitions.

Comment: Can I set up GRUB on 2nd partition, and load Ubuntu from there, instead of restoring it in boot sector? On boot loader, when I hit ESC it takes me to 2nd partition, that is where I was hoping to set up GRUB. I understand that grub does not have to be in boot sector of the HD, that it can reside and be executed from it's partition. Or am I way off on this one?..Thank You

Comment: @Dan: No, you need to install the first boot loader stage of Grub (or something compatible) as the main boot loader of the entire drive. This first stage can then load the seconds stage of Grub which will typically reside inside a partition. The second stage can then, among other, defer to other boot loaders (e. g. that of Windows or maybe Veracrypt). See the update to my answer.

Comment: @Dan: As you’ve never accepted an answer before: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the number at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!